# Stub calls to third party services using WireMock

Tags: integration-testing, stub, stubbing, wiremock

I tried to find a way to stub calls to external services via `WireMock`. `WireMock` easily mocks any relative URL, but what if we want to intercept a REST call, which was sent from our node to some 3rd party service and return predefined response? Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Anything useful?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, check out the proxying section in the docs: http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying

Comment: Is there a working sample for the above case? Docs doesn't look that helpful to me

Comment: It's not possible, proxying section is all about intercepting call to local wiremock and "forward" to a defined remote service (possibly on another host). I guess the question is about the other way around....so client calling http://remoteHost.some/service and the answer to be intercepted by wiremock running inside the same VM or anyway on the same host as the client itself

Comment: I agree... this is also my understanding as of now

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround by extracting the host as application configuration.

So if your application sends requests to:

```
http://thired-party-service.com/someEndPoint
```

You can extract the host as configuration param:

```
host=http://thired-party-service.com/
```

Now when you running in a test context fill the host param with same host as your WireMock server, for example:

```
host=http://localhost:8080/
```

Now you can use WireMock stubs as usual.